# Compare string to array of object

Tags: javascript

I come up with this solution to compare a string to an array of object. However, I don't think this is the best solution. Any suggestion on how to make this function perform better for large array of object?

```js
var a = "blAh";
var b = [{
  "tag": "tag1",
  "icons": ["blah"]
}, {
  "tag": "tag2",
  "icons": ["Blah", "apple", "banana", "bLaH"]
}];

// Desired output "tag1, tag2"
function getTitle(tags, icon) {
  let arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].icons.forEach(elem => {
      if (icon.toLowerCase() === elem.toLowerCase()) {
        if (!arr.includes(tags[i].tag)) {
          arr.push(tags[i].tag);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  return arr.join(', ');
}
console.log(getTitle(b, a));
```

Comment: You can do `icon = icon.toLowerCase()` before entering the loop, but what is your actual issue? Lookup speed can be greatly increased using an index, but building the index is additional overhead. You could also build an index of stored values so instead of `!arr.includes(tags[i].tag)` you'd have a property lookup: `!(tags[i].tag in seenValues)`, etc.

Comment: The only improvment I guess is to put `icon.toLowerCase()` at the very begining of the function (store it in a variable so you won't call it over and over again). If you are looking for an improvment in readability not performance, then use `reduce`, `filter` and `concat`, ...

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir—this is where it goes to opinion: loops are very good for performance and quite readable. Array extras can reduce typing though. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for readability, I would use the following :

```
var res = b.filter(el =>
  el.icons.length < 0 
    ? false
    : el.icons.map(icon =>  icon.toLowerCase()).indexOf(a.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1
).map(el => el.tag).join(', ');
```

But for performances, this one would be better :

```
var res = [];
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  if (b[i].icons.length < 0) {
  } else {
     for (j = 0; j < b[i].icons.length; j++)
       b[i].icons[j] = b[i].icons[j].toLowerCase();
    if (b[i].icons.indexOf(a.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1)
      res.push(b[i].tag);
  }
}
res = res.join(', ');
```

Here is why :

- `indexOf` is always faster than `includes` (or equal in old versions of chrome). [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/str-indexof-vs-str-includes)
- `for` loops are always faster than array methods like filter,  map or reduce. benchmarks : [map](https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance/6), [filter](https://jsperf.com/javascript-array-filter-versus-loop)

Also it's intresting to see that [`for` loops are faster than `indexOf` in the latest version of chrome (60)](https://jsperf.com/js-for-loop-vs-array-indexof/8)

Hope it helps,
Best regards